# trigger cursor move event upon page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, cursor

I'm working on a portfolio website that is a full browser sized container which swaps images when moving the cursor from left to right.

the header and captions are involved in the jquery script in order to change their color according to the image that is shown.

this seems to work great but the only downside is that the header & caption are not visible until the cursor is moved across the browser when you just loaded the site.

Is there a way to make the text appear upon site load? like triggering a mouseover event when it loads so the text is already there? or maybe some less complicated fix...
In any case thanks so much for the help!

```js
$.fn.swinger = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $container = $(this);
        $container.css({
            "position": "relative"
        });
        var $images = $container.find("img");
        $images.css({
            
        });
        var $middleImage = $($images[Math.floor($images.length / 2)]);
        $middleImage.css({
            "z-index": "2",
            "position": "relative"
        });
        var columnsCount = $images.length;
        $images.each((i, img) => {
            var left = `${100 / columnsCount * i}%`;
            var width = `${100 / columnsCount}%`;
            var $column = $(`<span style="z-index:999;position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:${left};width:${width}"></span>`);
            $(img).after($column);
            $column.hover(() => {
                $images.css({
                    "z-index": "1",
                    "position": "absolute"
                });
                $(img).css({
                    "z-index": "2",
                    "position": "relative"
                });
                // just added one line
                $(".caption").text($(img).attr("alt"));
                
                $(".caption")
                .text($(img).attr("alt"))
                .css('color', $(img).data('color'));

                $('header').css('color', $(img).data('color'))
        
            });
        })
    });
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {

}

.left-holder {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 55px;
    width: 250px; }

div.swinger-container {
    text-align: center; /* ensures the image is always in the h-middle */
    overflow: hidden; 
    width: 100vw;
height: calc(100vh);

}

div.swinger-container img {
    object-fit: cover;
-o-object-position: center center;
object-position: center center;
width: 100%;
height: 100% !important;
  }

  header {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: -2px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    transition: all .2s; }
    header.header-about {
      color: white !important;
      background-color: white; }
    header h1, header h2, header .about {
      font-size: 1em;
      font-weight: 400;
      display: block;
      line-height: 1.2em;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0; }
    header h1 {
      text-align: left; }
    header a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      line-height: 1; }
    header .about {
      text-align: left;
      padding-bottom: 2px; }

      

        .caption {
            
    
            z-index: 100;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 20px;
            max-width: 500px;
            text-align: center;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 50vw;
            
    
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <title>website title</title>
    <script src="./jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <header>
        <div class="left-holder">
            <h1>my name</h1> 
            <h2>what I do</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">

        </div>
       
    </header>

    <div class="slides">
        <div class="swinger-container">
        
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1447703693928-9cd89c8d3ac5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80" data-color="white" alt="Caption 1"/>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502239608882-93b729c6af43?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class=“swinger_img_white” alt="Caption 2"/>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516557070061-c3d1653fa646?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-color="white" alt="Caption 3"/>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1468657988500-aca2be09f4c6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class=“swinger_img_white” alt="Caption 4"/>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488554378835-f7acf46e6c98?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80" data-color="white" alt="Caption 5"/>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491895200222-0fc4a4c35e18?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80" class=“swinger_img_black” alt="Caption 6"/>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517816743773-6e0fd518b4a6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-color="black" alt="Caption 7"/>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1548685913-fe6678babe8d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1923&q=80" data-color="black" alt="Caption 8"/>
            
        </div> 
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(init);
        function init() 
        {
            $(".swinger-container").swinger();
        }
</script>

   <script src="swinger.js"></script>
    
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't you just display the first setup?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Well it takes a mouse event to show the first caption so can't you just do that when page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this okay for you?
I have just used the first image as a default one. Then the mouse events will do the rest.

Added this in init:

```
let defaultImage = $("#default-image");
$(".caption").text(defaultImage.attr("alt")).css('color', $(defaultImage).data('color'));
$('header').css('color', $(defaultImage).data('color'));
```

```js
$.fn.swinger = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    var $container = $(this);
    $container.css({
      "position": "relative"
    });
    var $images = $container.find("img");
    $images.css({

    });
    var $middleImage = $($images[Math.floor($images.length / 2)]);
    $middleImage.css({
      "z-index": "2",
      "position": "relative"
    });
    var columnsCount = $images.length;
    $images.each((i, img) => {
      var left = `${100 / columnsCount * i}%`;
      var width = `${100 / columnsCount}%`;
      var $column = $(`<span style="z-index:999;position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:${left};width:${width}"></span>`);
      $(img).after($column);
      $column.hover(() => {
        $images.css({
          "z-index": "1",
          "position": "absolute"
        });
        $(img).css({
          "z-index": "2",
          "position": "relative"
        });
        // just added one line
        $(".caption").text($(img).attr("alt"));

        $(".caption")
          .text($(img).attr("alt"))
          .css('color', $(img).data('color'));

        $('header').css('color', $(img).data('color'))

      });
    })
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {}

.left-holder {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 55px;
  width: 250px;
}

div.swinger-container {
  text-align: center;
  /* ensures the image is always in the h-middle */
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vh);
}

div.swinger-container img {
  object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-position: center center;
  object-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100% !important;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: -2px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
}

header.header-about {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: white;
}

header h1,
header h2,
header .about {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

header h1 {
  text-align: left;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1;
}

header .about {
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.caption {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
  <title>website title</title>
  <script src="./jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="left-holder">
      <h1>my name</h1>
      <h2>what I do</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="caption">

    </div>

  </header>

  <div class="slides">
    <div class="swinger-container">

      <img id="default-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1447703693928-9cd89c8d3ac5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80" data-color="white" alt="Caption 1" />
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502239608882-93b729c6af43?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class=“swinger_img_white” alt="Caption 2" />
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516557070061-c3d1653fa646?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-color="white" alt="Caption 3" />
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1468657988500-aca2be09f4c6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class=“swinger_img_white” alt="Caption 4" />
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488554378835-f7acf46e6c98?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80" data-color="white" alt="Caption 5" />
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491895200222-0fc4a4c35e18?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80" class=“swinger_img_black” alt="Caption 6" />
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517816743773-6e0fd518b4a6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" data-color="black" alt="Caption 7" />
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1548685913-fe6678babe8d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1923&q=80" data-color="black" alt="Caption 8" />

    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(init);

    function init() {
      $(".swinger-container").swinger();
      
      // Just prepare the first setup here
      // Note that I have added the ID default-image to the first image 
      let defaultImage = $("#default-image");
      $(".caption").text(defaultImage.attr("alt")).css('color', $(defaultImage).data('color'));
      $('header').css('color', $(defaultImage).data('color'));
    }
  </script>

  <script src="swinger.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work somewhat, but the caption still stays behind.
also I'm wondering how to bring the text back to the foreground as I'm unable to select it now.

Comment: I managed to work it out, works great ty!